# Footer Cell not getting displayed inside *ngFor in Mat-Table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm trying to show the sum at bottom of my table.

I followed exactly the same steps as mentioned in the documentation but still not working.

Below is my template code

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="transactions" matSort class="table table-hover">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let columnName of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="columnName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-danger">{{ columnName }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row[columnName] }}</td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="getRecord(row)"></tr>
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ total }}</td>
</table>
```

In component

```
  total = this.transactions.map(t => t.cost).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
```

Below is my working example. Please tell me what Im doing wrong here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehc6fn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.ts

Comment: Have a closer look at the difference in the example and the code you are trying to write. Should be easy.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/jampglnqxyyx?file=src/app/table-footer-row-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="transactions" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Item Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Item </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let transaction"> {{transaction.item}} </td>
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Cost Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cost </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let transaction"> {{transaction.cost | currency}} </td>
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{getTotalCost() | currency}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

check [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-footer)

**Updated**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="transactions" matSort class="table table-hover">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let columnName of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="columnName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-danger">{{ columnName }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row[columnName] }}</td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>
          {{columnName === 'item' ? 'Total': getTotalCost()}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="getRecord(row)"></tr>
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

[updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-footer)

Comment: This is the default solution this is not i'm expecting. I wanted to do this with dynamic Columns like i provided

Comment: each column and rows rendering inside for loop

Comment: yes it's working but just one issue, in Total it showing as `NAN` instead of the number

Comment: I used same html code in you stackblitz url. It's working fine.

Comment: I tried with different  data, numbers as floating digits